# Reporting Service deployment error - Connection could not be made to the report server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, configuration

i'm using sql server 2005 and i tried to make a reporting service project using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 but when i make a deploy my report to my Report Server i got this error !!

Microsoft Report Designer:

"A connection could not be made to the report server http://localhost/reportserver."

Additional Information:

The operation has timed out (System.Web.Services)

So, can any one help me on that and for .. i thought that its something with reporting service configuration, but i made all the configuration SQL reporing service may need.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When deploying a SSRS-report you need to make sure that the windows-id or credentials being used to deploy the report have appropriate rights on the report server or not (and also for the folder on the report-server where you are trying to deploy).
Though the location (http://[Server Name]/ReportServer/) for deploying the report doesn't have to be that of the database from which that report query is going to extract the data, the windows-id has to have at least "content-manager" rights.

Please see if this helps.

Thanks.